# How to type hint python magic __get__ method

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing, magic-methods, python-descriptors

Suppose we have the following classes:

```py
class Foo:
   def __init__(self, method):
       self.method = method

   def __get__(self, instance, owner):
       if instance is None:
          return self
       return self.method(instance)


class Bar:
    @Foo
    def do_something(self) -> int:
        return 1


Bar().do_something  # is 1
Bar.do_something    # is Foo object
```

How to type hint `__get__` and `method` correctly so that Pylance understands `Bar().do_something` is of the return type of `do_something`? (like a standard `property`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to [overload](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload) the [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method.

I do not use VSCode myself, but I tested the code below with MyPy and I would expect Pyright to infer the types correctly as well.

### Python `>=3.9`

To make this as flexible as possible, I would suggest making `Foo` generic in terms of

1. the class using the descriptor/decorator,
2. the parameter specification of the decorated method, and
3. the return type of the decorated method.

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union, overload
from typing_extensions import Concatenate, ParamSpec, Self

T = TypeVar("T")    # class using the descriptor
P = ParamSpec("P")  # parameter specs of the decorated method
R = TypeVar("R")    # return value of the decorated method


class Foo(Generic[T, P, R]):
    method: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]

    def __init__(self, method: Callable[Concatenate[T, P], R]) -> None:
        self.method = method

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: T, owner: object) -> R: ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: object) -> Self: ...

    def __get__(self, instance: Union[T, None], owner: object) -> Union[Self, R]:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.method(instance)
```

Demo:

```py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING


class Bar:
    @Foo
    def do_something(self) -> int:
        return 1


a = Bar().do_something
b = Bar.do_something

print(type(a), type(b))  # <class 'int'> <class '__main__.Foo'>
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_locals()
```

Running MyPy over this gives the desired output:

```
note: Revealed local types are:
note:     a: builtins.int
note:     b: Foo[Bar, [], builtins.int]
```

**NOTE**: (thanks to @SUTerliakov for pointing some of this out)

- If you are on Python `>=3.10`, you can import [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate) and [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) directly from `typing` and you can use the `|`-notation instead of [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union).
- If you are on Python `>=3.11` you can import [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) directly from `typing` as well, meaning you won't need `typing_extensions` at all.

---

### Python `<3.9`

Without [`Concatenate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Concatenate), [`ParamSpec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec) and [`Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self) we can still make `Foo` generic in terms of the return value of the decorated method:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Union, overload

R = TypeVar("R")    # return value of the decorated method


class Foo(Generic[R]):
    method: Callable[..., R]

    def __init__(self, method: Callable[..., R]) -> None:
        self.method = method

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: None, owner: object) -> Foo[R]: ...

    @overload
    def __get__(self, instance: object, owner: object) -> R: ...

    def __get__(self, instance: object, owner: object) -> Union[Foo[R], R]:
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return self.method(instance)
```

MyPy output for the same demo script from above:

```
note: Revealed local types are:
note:     a: builtins.int
note:     b: Foo[builtins.int]
```

Comment: Could you add a reference to `typing_extensions` to clear up that python requirements are only because of stl `typing` module capabilities? Your first solution will work perfectly on py3.9 with `typing_extensions` imports of `Self`, `Concatenate`, and `ParamSpec`.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Thanks. I edited my answer. You are right. It is sufficient to distinguish between `<3.9` and `>=3.9`. (I also wrongly used `|` union notation in the older version.)

Comment: Actually pipe union notation was also fine, because you have annotations future-import and use pipe in annotations only:)

Comment: thank you for your thorough answer Daniil

Comment: @feiyang472 Glad I could help. If this solved your problem and answered your question satisfactorily, consider marking it as _accepted_ to signal this to other users.